CosmosException: BadRequest in Spring boot Example
I am trying to filter the employee data by addressType from cosmosdb by using join in my spring boot application.
Below is the employee data in cosmosdb
{
    "id": "125",
    "name": "Dolly",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "addressType": "home",
            "street": "Nagpur"
        },
        {
            "addressType": "office",
            "street": "Pune"
        }
    ] }

This is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.employee.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>employee-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>employee-service</name>
    <description>employee service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.11.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-data-cosmos</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

below is my Repository class
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CosmosRepository<Employee, String> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM c JOIN a IN c.addresses WHERE a.addressType = @addressType")
    List<Employee> findByAddressType(@Param("addressType") String addressType);

}

Below is my service class
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


    
    public List<Employee> findByAddressType(String addressType) {
        
        return employeeRepository.findByAddressType(addressType);
    }

}

Below is my employeeController
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    

    @GetMapping("/employees/by-address-type")
    public List<Employee> getEmployeesByAddressType(@RequestParam String addressType) {
        return employeeService.findByAddressType(addressType);
    }

}

When I am trying to call "@GetMapping("/employees/by-address-type?addressType=home")" api I am getting below error
DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.c.implementation.SqlQuerySpecLogger  : SELECT * FROM c JOIN a IN c.addresses WHERE a.addressType = @addressType
2024-06-14T10:47:29.566+05:30 DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.c.implementation.caches.AsyncCache   : cache[dbs/sscmxMaster/colls/employees] doesn't exist, computing new value
2024-06-14T10:47:29.567+05:30 DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.c.implementation.caches.AsyncLazy    : constructor
2024-06-14T10:47:29.570+05:30 DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.c.implementation.caches.AsyncLazy    : using Function<Mono<TValue>> com.azure.cosmos.implementation.caches.RxCollectionCache$$Lambda$1601/0x000001b4c57d4000@5bf8c934
2024-06-14T10:47:29.781+05:30 DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.c.implementation.caches.AsyncCache   : set cache[v+xOAMHU++M=]={"id":"employees","indexingPolicy":{"indexingMode":"consistent","automatic":true,"includedPaths":[{"path":"/*"}],"excludedPaths":[{"path":"/\"_etag\"/?"}]},"partitionKey":{"paths":["/null"],"kind":"Hash"},"defaultTtl":-1,"uniqueKeyPolicy":{"uniqueKeys":[]},"conflictResolutionPolicy":{"mode":"LastWriterWins","conflictResolutionPath":"/_ts","conflictResolutionProcedure":""},"backupPolicy":{"type":1},"geospatialConfig":{"type":"Geography"},"_rid":"v+xOAMHU++M=","_ts":1718259475,"_self":"dbs/v+xOAA==/colls/v+xOAMHU++M=/","_etag":"\"00003313-0000-0c00-0000-666a8f130000\"","_docs":"docs/","_sprocs":"sprocs/","_triggers":"triggers/","_udfs":"udfs/","_conflicts":"conflicts/"}
2024-06-14T10:47:29.788+05:30 DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.c.implementation.caches.AsyncCache   : cache[dbs/sscmxMaster/colls/employees] exists
2024-06-14T10:47:29.791+05:30 DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.c.implementation.caches.AsyncCache   : Returning cache[dbs/sscmxMaster/colls/employees] as it is different from obsoleteValue
2024-06-14T10:47:30.600+05:30 DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.c.i.WebExceptionRetryPolicy          : WebExceptionRetryPolicy() No retrying on un-retryable exceptions on endpoint https://sscmx-dev-db-account-northeurope.documents.azure.com:443/, operationType = QueryPlan, resourceType = Document, count = 0, isAddressRefresh = false
2024-06-14T10:47:30.603+05:30 DEBUG 14264 --- [supplier-dataproducts] [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.c.implementation.ClientRetryPolicy   : retry count 1, isReadRequest true, canUseMultipleWriteLocations false, due to failure:

com.azure.cosmos.CosmosException: {"innerErrorMessage":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"One of the input values is invalid.\\r\\nActivityId: 34feb19e-8055-4bf9-8880-dd668d86c6ec, Windows/10.0.20348 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.18.0\"}, StatusCode: BadRequest","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.57.0 Windows11/10.0 JRE/17.0.10 az-sd-cos/5.11.0","activityId":"34feb19e-8055-4bf9-8880-dd668d86c6ec","requestLatencyInMs":814,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2024-06-14T05:17:29.785424500Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2024-06-14T05:17:30.599804400Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":["north europe"],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryCount":0,"retryLatency":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatisticsList":[{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"QueryPlan","resourceType":"Document","statusCode":400,"subStatusCode":0,"requestCharge":0.0,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2024-06-14T05:17:29.791924500Z","durationInMilliSecs":510.9615},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2024-06-14T05:17:30.302886Z","durationInMilliSecs":0.0},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2024-06-14T05:17:30.302886Z","durationInMilliSecs":1.9967},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2024-06-14T05:17:30.304882700Z","durationInMilliSecs":283.7429},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2024-06-14T05:17:30.588625600Z","durationInMilliSecs":0.0}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null,"responsePayloadSizeInBytes":0,"exceptionMessage":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"One of the input values is invalid.\\r\\nActivityId: 34feb19e-8055-4bf9-8880-dd668d86c6ec, Windows/10.0.20348 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.18.0\"}, StatusCode: BadRequest","exceptionResponseHeaders":"{Server=Compute, x-ms-gatewayversion=2.0.0, Content-Length=215, Date=Fri, 14 Jun 2024 05:17:30 GMT, x-ms-activity-id=34feb19e-8055-4bf9-8880-dd668d86c6ec, Content-Type=application/json, x-ms-substatus=0}"}],"samplingRateSnapshot":1.0,"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"60247 KB","availableMemory":"4031657 KB","systemCpuLoad":"(2024-06-14T05:17:13.744198800Z 5.4%), (2024-06-14T05:17:18.739241700Z 5.2%), (2024-06-14T05:17:23.737563400Z 4.1%), (2024-06-14T05:17:28.746632200Z 5.9%)","availableProcessors":8},"clientCfgs":{"id":1,"machineId":"uuid:26f55ade-8d88-4c44-8b80-ed33cf42a003","connectionMode":"DIRECT","numberOfClients":1,"excrgns":"[]","clientEndpoints":{"https://sscmx-dev-db-account.documents.azure.com:443/":1},"connCfg":{"rntbd":"(cto:PT5S, nrto:PT5S, icto:PT0S, ieto:PT1H, mcpe:130, mrpc:30, cer:true)","gw":"(cps:1000, nrto:PT1M, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false, rv: true)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])","proactiveInitCfg":"","e2ePolicyCfg":"","sessionRetryCfg":""}}}
    at com.azure.cosmos.BridgeInternal.createCosmosException(BridgeInternal.java:478) ~[azure-cosmos-4.57.0.jar:4.57.0]
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.validateOrThrow(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:504) ~[azure-cosmos-4.57.0.jar:4.57.0]
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.lambda$toDocumentServiceResponse$1(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:365) ~[azure-cosmos-4.57.0.jar:4.57.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]

I tried
SELECT *
FROM c
JOIN a IN c.addresses
WHERE a.addressType = 'home'

in cosmosdb data explore and it is working as expected but if i am using same query in spring boot it is not working.
I also tried by without @Query as well
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CosmosRepository<Employee, String> {

    List<Employee> findByAddressesAddressType(String addressType);

}

I am getting 200 response but result is blank array []

Please edit to provide concise details (a [mcve]) about the issue you're getting, along with where the error is happening. Right now, it's hard to figure this out: the exception output is fairly large, with the error description "One of the input values is invalid." and it's unclear what exact code and parameters you executed that caused this error (what input value was invalid? what was the value?)

FYI the vast majority of that exception dump isn't really helpful - please clean things up to just show the pertinent error output details.

The occurrence of the error is because the mismatch of partition key, if the partition key is id in the Azure Cosmos DB but in the code used as Id so, rename to id or add an attribute. Make sure the data type of the id is string. Try with the below code which executed successfully to retrieve data which is having addressType: home from Azure Cosmos DB Container as you can see in the below output.
pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cosmosdb-query</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Web Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Azure Cosmos DB SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>4.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Jackson Databind for JSON processing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Test (for testing purposes) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Config.java:
@Configuration
public class CosmosConfig {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "*****";
    private static final String KEY = "*****";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "firstDb";
    private static final String CONTAINER_NAME = "firstCont";

    @Bean
    public CosmosClient cosmosClient() {
        return new CosmosClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .key(KEY)
                .preferredRegions(List.of("West US"))
                .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.EVENTUAL)
                .buildClient();
    }

    @Bean
    public CosmosDatabase cosmosDatabase(CosmosClient cosmosClient) {
        return cosmosClient.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public CosmosContainer cosmosContainer(CosmosDatabase cosmosDatabase) {
        return cosmosDatabase.getContainer(CONTAINER_NAME);
    }
}

Service.java:
@Service
public class CosmosDbService {

    @Autowired
    private CosmosContainer cosmosContainer;

    public void executeQuery() {
        String query = "SELECT c.id, c.name, a.addressType, a.street " +
                       "FROM c " +
                       "JOIN a IN c.addresses " +
                       "WHERE a.addressType = 'home'";

        CosmosPagedIterable<ObjectNode> items = cosmosContainer.queryItems(query, new CosmosQueryRequestOptions(), ObjectNode.class);

        for (ObjectNode item : items) {
            System.out.println(item.toString()); 
        }
    }
}

Output:
{"id":"125","name":"Dolly","addressType":"home","street":"Nagpur"}


